# Ruby: Delete all key value pair in hash with a particular value

Tags: ruby, hash

My hash:

```
hash={value1: "2",value2: "1",value3: "6",value4: "2" }
```

What I want is to remove all key value pairs with value of "2" like this:

```
hash={value2: "1",value3: "6"}
```

How to do that?

Comment: Good question. I'm looking for that too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How is this using <kbd>[**`delete_if`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if)</kbd>  ?

```
hash={value1: "2",value2: "1",value3: "6",value4: "2" } 
hash.delete_if{|_,v| v == "2"}
# => {:value2=>"1", :value3=>"6"}
hash
# => {:value2=>"1", :value3=>"6"}
```

If you don't want to modify the original `hash` then you could use also <kbd>[**`Hash#reject`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject)</kbd> :

```
hash={value1: "2",value2: "1",value3: "6",value4: "2" } 
new_hash=hash.reject{|_,v| v == "2"}
# => {:value2=>"1", :value3=>"6"}
hash # => {:value1=>"2", :value2=>"1", :value3=>"6", :value4=>"2"}
```

Comment: That's cool!! I didn't knew ruby has a built in method for that. Thanks.